# The Seven Siblings

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, language, geography

**PREFACE**

This is a more lively try on "Where do I want to go next?" riddles, hope you like it!

**THE PUZZLE**

Hi, here are us, the seven siblings, but one is missing!

***The brothers:***

A: Let's introduce ourselves without our family name. It's boring to be formal, right?

B: Ok, I'll go first. Yo, I am a tall bird! People always say "Careful your red cap dont hit the sky"!

C: Hey there, those Chinese kids will often mistake me as a turtle!

A: And I am often mistaken with my friend a little bit souther.
Do you know...

B: Shut up!

***The sisters:***

D: Hi there! You know, we are all hands in hands, so I will introduce us all to you.

My younger sister has a starry sky,

But lo! My queen shines alone.

My other sister has a lot of gold,

yet is the smallest and youngest in the trio.

**QUESTION**

D: To be or not to be, that is the question. JKJK

Now, o my friend, guess who we are, and figure out who our missing brother is!

**HINTS**

Reminder:

> Pay attention to the tags

Hint 1:

> Most of us are only introducing our names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the siblings are

> countries beginning with the letter U.

A: I am often mistaken with my friend a little bit souther.

> This is **Uzbekistan**, whose name without the family name U sounds similar to Pakistan which is to the south. (edited based on OP's comment)

B: Yo, I am a tall bird! People always say "Careful your red cap dont hit the sky"!

> The tall bird is a crane, making the country **Ukraine**.

C: Hey there, those Chinese kids will often mistake me as a turtle!

> The Mandarin word for turtle is 乌龟 (wūguī), which I suppose sounds a bit like **Uruguay** without the initial U.

The "D" sisters are

> Countries beginning with "United". (Hands in hands – get it?)

D1: My younger sister has a starry sky,

> **United States** with its star-spangled flag.

D2: But lo! My queen shines alone.

> **United Kingdom** with her royal highness.

D3: My other sister has a lot of gold, yet is the smallest and youngest in the trio.

> The wealthy **United Arab Emirates** is smaller than both the US and the UK, and became independent last.

The missing brother would then be

> **Uganda**.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Hmm, is it then rot13[Hmorxvfgna orvat pbashfrq jvgu bar bs gur bgure 'fgnaf, naq gur zvffvat bar vf Htnaqn]? Both Tu-- and Ta-- are to the south, but not sure which one is commonly confused with U...

Comment: rot13[Lrc, gung'f gur gjb. Ubjrire, V zrnag Cnxvfgna gb or pbashfrq nf erzbivat gur Hm jbhyq eraqre gurz fbhaq irel nyvxr]

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Ah, I get it now. Edited!

Answer (score 7):

I don't have a full solution but enough that I feel comfortable sharing this guess (for the first time on this board!)

> The siblings are countries whose names end in "stan" and I think the missing one is Pakistan

Sisters.

> The borders of Uzbekistan, Kyrgyzstan, and Tajikistan look like they're "holding hands". Their flags seem to match the clues.

My youngest sister has a starry sky,

> The flag of Uzbekistan has a starry sky.

But lo! My queen shines alone.

> The flag of Tajikistan has a shiny crown.

My other sister has a lot of gold,

yet is the smallest in the trio.

> The flag of Kyrgyzstan has a lot of gold and it's the smallest country by population.

For the brothers, I had to stretch a bit more.

B: Ok, I'll go first. Yo, I am a tall bird! People always say "Careful your red cap dont hit the sky"!

> I'm guessing this refers to turkeys, and Turkmenistan.

C: Hey there, those Chinese kids will often mistake me as a turtle!

> Kazakhstan has a big border with china and if you squint it looks like a turtle.

A: And I am often mistaken with my friend a little bit souther. Do you know...

> Afghanistan and Pakistan are often confused as "middle eastern countries that have a lot of wars." Of these Afghanistan is to the north.

This leaves

> Pakistan

as the remaining member.

Comment: A very good and reasonable try, +1! You also get what I mean by family, but what I am looking for is another family. You got one in the seven right though, but not in the right position. Keep it up!

Answer (score 4):

Well, could be something with (but is totally wrong):

> **Orion** , it has 7 stars, and for thai people it is "Turtle." but…
>  I found Black Tortoise from Chinese constellations.
>  Guy "B" fits Vermilion Bird from Chinese constellations?

Maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Yes, sorry you are totally wrong, keep it up!